# Show details during compile

Tags: maven, maven-3

I have a Maven project which compiles JavaFX 8 application. Can you tell me how I can display detailed output during compile time? Usually this is done by -X argument but I want to configure this into the POM file.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the configuration of the [maven-compiler-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/) to add such supplemental arguments like this:

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1</version>
          <configuration>
            <compilerArgs>
              <arg>-Xmaxerrs=1000</arg>
              <arg>-Xlint</arg>
            </compilerArgs>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

Furthermore you can use the verbose option to enhance the output like this:

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1</version>
          <configuration>
            <verbose>true</verbose>
            ..
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

Comment: I get his error message: `Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project DX-57DC: Fatal error compiling: invalid flag: -Xmaxerrs=1000 -> [Help 1]`

Comment: You shouldn't take my flags just use them which are needed for the use case you have.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to khmarbaise's answer:

`-X` compiler parameters that require values (eg. `-Xmaxwarns`) need to be passed to a separate `<arg>` tag.

Example:

```
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <compilerArgs>
        <arg>-Xlint:all</arg>
        <arg>-Xmaxwarns</arg>
        <arg>50000</arg>
      </compilerArgs>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Tested with:

- Maven 3.0.5 + Maven Compiler plugin 3.2
- Maven 3.3.9 + Maven Compiler plugin 3.6.0